# Array of n size in Java

Tags: java

This was asked in my interview:

> To print duplicate values from an array.

I am storing all duplicate values in array b. Finally storing them in hash set and printing the hash set. Only reason I am storing them in hash set is because I only want unique value from the duplicates. Like if I have {1,2,2,1} in my array then it should only print {1,2}.

Below program works fine but I have allocated a fixed size for array b (size = 100 in below program) and I want that on run time its value should be updated with the number of duplicates found. For example: if I have 10 duplicate values in my array a then b then b should become 10.

I checked a lot before posting this question, also I think this could be done with ArrayList but I am not sure how to write for array b.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class duplicate_values_hash {

    public static void main(String aa[])
    {   
        Integer a[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 10, 11, 90, 8,12, 5, 4, 5, 8};
        Arrays.sort(a);

        Integer b[] = new Integer[100]; // How to update on runtime

        int len,i,j = 0;
        len = a.length;

        for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(a[i-1] == a[i])
            {   
                j = j + 1;  
                b[j] = a[i];
            }
        }

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(b);
        HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        hs.addAll(list);
        System.out.println(hs);

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't found the duplicates yet.

Comment: Why do you have an intermediate array? Just add your input array directly to the `Set` and you're done.

Comment: Above program gives the duplicate but I am storing all duplicates in b and then passing them to hash set, so that I do not have any repetition of duplicates.

Comment: One purpose of a `HashSet`  is to eliminate duplicates. You're just repeating its job, but less efficiently.

Comment: also, java conventions state that class names need to uppercase, so `duplicate_values_hash` should be `Duplicate_Values_Hash` I remember learning this my first year, so make sure to have that down, if you have time to do so.

Comment: If you wanted to make an ArrayList for b, then you would do this: `ArrayList<Integer> newB = new ArrayList<Integer>();` and when you came to the point where you decide to add values, you would probably have a for-loop or something and do `newB.add(a, intValue)` where a is the factor that increases in your for-loop condition and intValue is the value you are entering.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically allocate by the **array** **a** size:

```
public static void main(String aa[]) {
    Integer a[] = {
        1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 10, 11, 90, 8, 12, 5, 4, 5, 8
    };
    Arrays.sort(a);

    Integer b[] = new Integer[a.length]; // How to update on runtime

    int len, i, j = 0;
    len = a.length;

    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i - 1] == a[i]) {
            b[j++] = a[i];
        }
    }

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(b));
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(list);
    System.out.println(hs);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @chengpohi. That is what I was looking for. But right now, the output is also showing a null.

Comment: Thanks again @chengpohi. You totally solved all my doubts!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does the samething

```
public static void main(String aa[])
{   
    Integer a[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 10, 11, 90, 8,12, 5, 4, 5, 8};

    int len = a.length;
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        hs.add(a[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(hs);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's this question really about? Dynamically sizing an array? Don't. Or use ArrayList, as it will resize.

Is it about finding how many duplicates in an array?

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for(int nextInt:myArrayOfPossibleDuplicates) {
    set.add(nextInt);
}
for(int nextInt:set) {
    System.out.println(nextInt);
}
System.out.println("There were " + myArrayOfPossibleDuplicates.length - set.size() + " additional items through duplication");
```

Or are you trying to work how many duplicates for each item? Do this with a map.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> howManyOfEach = new HashMap<>();
for(int nextInt:myArrayOfPossibleDuplicates) {
    if (!howManyOfEach.containsKey(nextInt)) {
       howManyOfEach.put(nextInt, 1);
    } else {
       howManyOfEach.put(nextInt, howManyOfEach.get(nextInt) + 1);
    }
}
for(Entry<Integer,Integer> item:howManyOfEach.entrySet()) { 
    System.out.println("Number " + item.key() + " -> " + item.value() + " time(s)");
}
```

Seems a bit pointless now your interview is over.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
> {
>     if(a[i-1] == a[i])
>     {   
>         j = j + 1;  
>         b[j] = a[i];
>     }
> }
> ```

You *could* do something like this, and it'll probably work given proper logic, but this would be minus points if I were looking for a suitable Java programmer (and not a graduate programmer), because this fails to understand Java.

To find duplicate entries, I'd expect something more like this:

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 10, 11, 90, 8,12, 5, 4, 5, 8};

Set<Integer> uniqueNums = new HashSet<>();
for (int num : nums) {
    if (!uniqueNums.add(num)) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

#### How this works

`Set<E>` is a data structure that only stores unique elements.  As such, if you try adding a value that's already in the set, `Set.add(E)` will return `false`.

The above loop goes through the numbers and tries to add each to the set.  Any number which `uniqueNums.add(num)` returns `false` are those that were already in the set, hence duplicates.

#### Resulting output

The above code prints this.

```
1
2
1
3
8
5
4
5
8
```

`1`, `5`, `8` are printed twice because they were *duplicated twice*. (i.e. Each had three in total.)

Now, what to do if you don't want to see duplicates of your duplicates?  *Answer: Use another `Set<E>`!*

Comment: That loop wouldn't work though unless duplicate values were next to each other. I dont see how it could work with the given nums array. Or am I misreading that loop somehow? Im taking about the example from OP

Comment: didnt notice the OP sorted them first. whoops

Comment: @JohnnyCoder Order doesn't matter.  See `Set.add()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)  Or better yet, give it a try it.